# What does -0400 mean in Timestamp('2014-09-19 12:21:21.747000-0400')?

Tags: python, pandas

I converted a series to EST with:

```
pd.to_datetime(my_series, unit='ms').apply(lambda x: x.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern'))
```

and the conversion, e.g. for one of the entries was:

- **Input:** `1411143681747`
- **Output:** `Timestamp('2014-09-19 12:21:21.747000-0400', tz='US/Eastern')`

What does `-0400` mean here?

Comment: It means that the EST time zone is four hours behind UTC.

Comment: FYI - no need to use apply here (tz_localize/convert are methods on index and series)

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. I tried that in the past without luck. I opened this question separately: [Unable to apply methods on timestamps in Pandas using Series built-ins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089670/unable-to-convert-time-zones-in-pandas)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an offset for the timezone from UTC. Eastern is 4 hours behind UTC right now.

Comment: Everyone does, sometimes, mate, no problem.