# Unable to apply methods on timestamps using Series built-ins

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, timestamp

On the following series:

```
0    1411161507178
1    1411138436009
2    1411123732180
3    1411167606146
4    1411124780140
5    1411159331327
6    1411131745474
7    1411151831454
8    1411152487758
9    1411137160544
Name: my_series, dtype: int64
```

This command (convert to timestamp, localize and convert to EST) works:

```
pd.to_datetime(my_series, unit='ms').apply(lambda x: x.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern'))
```

but **this one** fails:

```
pd.to_datetime(my_series, unit='ms').tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

with:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-58187a4b60f8> in <module>()
----> 1 lua = pd.to_datetime(df[column], unit='ms').tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern')

/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in tz_localize(self, tz, axis, copy, infer_dst)
   3492                 ax_name = self._get_axis_name(axis)
   3493                 raise TypeError('%s is not a valid DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex' %
-> 3494                                 ax_name)
   3495             else:
   3496                 ax = DatetimeIndex([],tz=tz)

TypeError: index is not a valid DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex
```

and so does **this one**:

```
my_series.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

with:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-0a7cb1e94e1e> in <module>()
----> 1 lua = df[column].tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern')

/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in tz_localize(self, tz, axis, copy, infer_dst)
   3492                 ax_name = self._get_axis_name(axis)
   3493                 raise TypeError('%s is not a valid DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex' %
-> 3494                                 ax_name)
   3495             else:
   3496                 ax = DatetimeIndex([],tz=tz)

TypeError: index is not a valid DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex
```

As far as I understand, the second approach above (the first one that fails) should work. Why does it fail?

Comment: I'm not sure why your first method works in fact, as for your second the error statement is quite clear, if in fact your index was your int64 values then the second approach works.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`tz_localize/tz_convert` act on the INDEX of the object, not on the values. Easiest to simply turn it into an index then localize and convert. If you then want a Series back you can use `to_series()`

```
In [47]: pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(s,unit='ms')).tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern')
Out[47]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-09-19 17:18:27.178000-04:00, ..., 2014-09-19 10:32:40.544000-04:00]
Length: 10, Freq: None, Timezone: US/Eastern
```

Answer (score 118):

As Jeff's answer mentions, `tz_localize()` and `tz_convert()` act on the index, not the data.  This was a huge surprise to me too.

Since Jeff's answer was written, Pandas 0.15 added a new `Series.dt` accessor that helps your use case.  You can now do this:

```
pd.to_datetime(my_series, unit='ms').dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

Comment: This is Great! I don't want to set TimeStamp as the Index, sometimes, we could have two TimeStamp as it is really frustrating that we have to convert it to index.

Comment: Seconded! This worked really well in our use case, too.  Thanks for documenting how to work around that quirk!

Comment: how we will compare this with general timestamp value suppose if i am takign current time and will compare it ... I am getting error TypeError: Cannot compare tz-naive and tz-aware datetime-like objects

Answer (score 3):

this work fine

```py
pd.to_datetime(my_series,unit='ms', utc=True).dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

Comment: You need to specify your version of panda's used is different from previous answer posted by John Zwink who states this answer earlier. You're answer is a derivative of his. Now as it is written its non-valid and I assume you want to have it "valid". Als explain why you wrote it like you did. This will gives your answer validity.

Comment: Once you question is updated accordingly my previous comment I will remove the down-vote and this comment.