# Failing to convert Pandas dataframe timestamp

Tags: python, indexing, pandas, timezone, timestamp

I'm pretty new to working with Pandas and am trying to figure out why this timestamp won't convert. As an example, one individual timestamp is the string `'2010-10-06 16:38:02'`. The code looks like this:

```
newdata = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "timestamp"], index = "timestamp")
newdata.index = newdata.index.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

And gets this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'tz_localize'
```

Someone commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903399/index-object-has-no-attribute-tz-localize) that tz_localize is not a method available to Index types, so I tried converting it as a column instead but that gave the error

```
TypeError: index is not a valid DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex
```

And then I found [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089670/unable-to-apply-methods-on-timestamps-using-series-built-ins), which says tz_localize *only* acts on the index, anyway.

If anyone could help me out it would be much appreciated! I'm using Pandas 0.15.2. I believe this code may have worked for someone else with an earlier version, but I can't switch.

EDIT:

Ok after messing around a little I found that this doesn't throw any errors and seemed to do what I want in the short-term: `newdata.index=pd.DatetimeIndex(newdata.index).tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/‌​Eastern')`

Comment: Erin, could you please add an answer and mark the question as resolved? Otherwise, it pops up as an unanswered one and confuses people...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been asked to add a formal answer instead of just editing my question, so here it is. Note it builds off the answer above, but that that one didn't quite work for me.

`newdata.index=pd.DatetimeIndex(newdata.index).tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/‌​Eastern')`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to first convert the index column to a series type in pandas :

```
newdata.index.to_series().tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

Comment: That's not the easy way to go. @Erin mentioned it and that's (IMHO) the way to go.