# When I insert pandas Series into dataframe, all values become NaN

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a pandas series that looks like this:

`>>> myseries 
 2012-01-01 15:20:00-05:00    2
 2012-01-01 15:30:00-05:00    1
 2012-01-01 15:40:00-05:00    0`...

And I try to put it into a dataframe as so:

`>>> mydf = pd.DataFrame(myseries, columns=["myseries"], index = myseries.index)`

and all the values become NaN for some reason:

`>>> mydf
2012-01-01 15:20:00-05:00      NaN
2012-01-01 15:30:00-05:00      NaN
2012-01-01 15:40:00-05:00      NaN`

I'm pretty confused. This seems like a really simple application. What am I doing wrong? By the way, replacing with `pd.DataFrame(myseries.values, columns=...)` fixes the problem, but why is it necessary? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the df you are using? Initializing a DataFrame using a Series works for me.

Comment: I can't post all the data if that's what you mean.. it's 200,000 rows. Its type is `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

Comment: If you create the df without specifying the index, and then redefine the index, does it work?

Comment: It does if I don't specify a column name, but I need to do that because the name needs to change. At that point, I must also define indexes to not get an empty dataframe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding new column to existing DataFrame in Python pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler:

```
s = pd.Series([0,1,2,3], index=pd.date_range('2014-01-01', periods=4), name='s')
df = pd.DataFrame(s)
print(df)
```

yields

```
            s
2014-01-01  0
2014-01-02  1
2014-01-03  2
2014-01-04  3
```

Comment: Yeah, I agree that works, but I guess I should have expanded a little. The initial column name of myseries needs to be dropped, and the new column name in my dataframe must be the name myseries. This is because I will subsequently fill in other columns as I calculate them. And once you specify columns=[], you seem to have to also specify index to get a non-null dataframe.

Comment: This is a simpler way to do it, but the OPs question is about why `mydf = pd.DataFrame(myseries, columns=["myseries"], index = myseries.index)` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
s = pd.Series([0,1,2,3], index=pd.date_range('2014-01-01', periods=4))
df = pd.DataFrame(s, columns=['s'], index=s.index)
print(df)
```

yields

```
            s
2014-01-01  0
2014-01-02  1
2014-01-03  2
2014-01-04  3
```

Comment: This works fine for me too, but my own data doesn't, unless I append the ".values". It's a mystery to me why.

Comment: What are the `dtypes` of the index and the values?

Comment: "dtype" is not allowed but "type" is `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`. Values are `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>` and indexes are `<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>`.

Comment: And, if something seems strange to you about that index, please see a workaround for an earlier line of the code I posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28910231/failing-to-convert-pandas-dataframe-timestamp).

Comment: Not sure how to help unless you post some reproducible code.

Comment: I understand. The thing is, I can't reproduce it with a sample case either. And I can't post 3 GB of data. This example above uses a series with all the same characteristics as mine, as far as I can tell, but results in different behavior when entering a dataframe. I'm stumped.

Comment: What do you mean dtype is not allowed? What are the results from `print(myseries.dtype, myseries.index.dtype)`?

Comment: Ah, I was trying `dtype(myseries.values)`. For your line, I get `(dtype('float64'), dtype('<M8[ns]'))` . If I do `s = pd.Series(np.array([0,1,2,3],dtype=np.float64), index=pd.date_range('2014-01-01', periods=4))`, the s df still works, though.