# Inserting a Pandas Series into a DataFrame makes all values Nan

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6

As the title implies I have converted two dictionaries into series like so and I tried to insert them into the data frame df.

```
first_series = pd.Series(first_dict, name='State Names')
second_series = pd.Series(second_dict, name='City Names')
column_loc=list(df.columns.values).index("ipAddr")
df.insert(column_loc+1, 'State Names', first_series)
df.insert(column_loc+2, 'City Names', second_series)
```

When I run this however I get

```
              ipAddr State Names City Names    ...       
respID                                         ...        
10018         ***.**.**.**  NaN        NaN     ...        
10025         **.**.**.**   NaN        NaN     ...
```

the series are as follows

```
10018       Bedford
10025     Vancouver
        ...    
10267        Lompoc
10280    Pikesville
Name: State Names, dtype: object
--------------------------------------------------------
10018          Ohio
10025    Washington
        ...    
10267    California
10280      Maryland
Name: City Names, dtype: object
```

I've checked that both the dictionaries and the resulting series are populated so I don't understand why this is occurring.

Thank you.

edit: A similar question got asked here but wasn't answered [When I insert pandas Series into dataframe, all values become NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934992/when-i-insert-pandas-series-into-dataframe-all-values-become-nan)

Comment: Can you give a short example of your DF and both Series which can reproduce the problem?

Comment: `10018       Bedford
10025     Vancouver
            ...    
10267        Lompoc
10280    Pikesville
Name: State Names, dtype: object` this is the first series and the second series is similar      `10018          Ohio
10025    Washington
            ...    
10267    California
10280      Maryland
Name: City Names, dtype: object` <br/> the index for both is the index of the data frame. I can't post the head of the data frame (character limit) but it is what's seen above. (apologies for the messy comment I'm new to stack and I don't know how to properly format yet)

Comment: Does your Series have the same length as the df?

Comment: Will df.insert(column_loc+1, 'State Names', first_series.values) work?

Comment: The series has 808 rows while the data frame has 809. This discrepancy is because the datable has named columns that take up a row.

Comment: Using first_series.values return `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index` To clarify, the series are inserted into the data frame but their values are lost.

Comment: That's the problem, your series has less rows than your df. Column is not counted in length. Do a len(df) and len(first_series), what's the output?

Comment: The data frame is 809 while the first_series is 808. I thought the column names might be considered in the rows because it was created by reading from an excel file. I'll try and find why there is a discrepancy in this code.

Comment: Once u remove the offending row from your df, it should work.

Comment: Turns out that was an issue but I just checked now and the length of the first_series and the df are the same yet the values are still NaN.

Comment: Did u use df.insert(column_loc+1, 'State Names', first_series.values)?

Comment: It totally worked now! Thank you so much the first time I tried the series.values it gave me an error because the series was the wrong length but now it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: No worries. Please accept the answer so this question will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the Series has less rows than the df. Also, Series.values need to be used while assigning it to a df column.